# How SHOW TABLE sql with TABLE GATEWAY ZF2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework2

How can I 'SHOW TABLE' with tablegateway in Zend Framework 2 ?

I would to execute "show table" sql with tablegateway, can i do it?

In sql I can query the db with this code

**"SHOW CREATE TABLE {table_name}"**

to have the creation table code.

E.G.

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `date_insert` datetime NOT NULL,
 `date_update` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

I have the table model that is declared in this way

```
class MyTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll($where = false)
    {
        $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();

        if ($where)
            $select->where($where);

        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        return $resultSet;
    }

    public function getShowCreateTable()
    {
        ?????
    }
}
```

How can I get the show create table?

Comment: What is 'tablegateway'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Zend\Db\Metadata`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.metadata.html) is the component you're looking for.  It allows you to extract data about the structure of the database your adapter is connected to.

There is also a TableGateway feature you can enable that will populate the TableGateway instance with metadata information.  [See the docs for it in this section](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html#tablegateway-features)

This will give you the raw structural information of the table, but won't automatically construct a CREATE TABLE statement for you. Since the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` query you mentioned is not universally supported you have two options:

- If you only need to support MySQL/MariaDB then the quickest route to what you're looking for is [the `query` method of the adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html#query-execution-through-zend-db-adapter-adapter-query).
- If you want it to be portable then you'll need to use one of the methods I described above and combine it with [`Zend\Db\Sql\Ddl`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.sql.ddl.html#creating-tables) to construct a cross-platform CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: I don't find the solution at my question...wath must I do?

Comment: I've revised my answer to add a bit more detail

Comment: thanks a lot ;) I've resolved in this way: 
  
  $adapter  = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
  
  $sql   = "SHOW CREATE TABLE {table_name}";
  
  $statement  = $adapter->query($sql);
  $result  = $statement->execute();
  
  $row = $result->current();